# Wifi keeps crashing, wifi says its using wl driver but wl driver not found in /lib/modules

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I'm using a Banana Pi M2 Zero with Ubuntu 16.04.3. The wifi works great at first but disconnects after about 5 minutes, and this error shows up in the syslog

```
INTERNAL ERROR: FIRMWARE HALTED : set BUS DOWN
CONSOLE: eclaim section 1: Returned 78856 bytes to the heap
CONSOLE: 000000.056 wl0: wlc_enable_probe_req: state down, deferring setting of host flags
CONSOLE: 000000.840 wl0: wl_open
CONSOLE: 000000.864 wl0: wlc_enable_probe_req: state down, deferring setting of host flags
CONSOLE: 000002.188 wl_nd_ra_filter_clear_cache: Enter..
CONSOLE: 000882.062 internal error, 3984154888/882062
CONSOLE: 000882.062 
CONSOLE: FWID 01-3621395e
CONSOLE: flags 1
CONSOLE: 000882.062 
CONSOLE: TRAP c(7fd30): pc 1106e, lr 1104f, sp 7fd84, cpsr 6000000c, spsr 61000010
CONSOLE: 000882.062   r0 2d, r1 7dab4, r2 1, r3 0, r4 7ad68, r5 ed796108, r6 4d5fa
CONSOLE: 000882.062   r7 da, r8 1, r9 50490, r10 50490, r11 0, r12 0
CONSOLE: 000882.062 
CONSOLE:    sp+0 0000002d 0007dab4 00000001 00000000
CONSOLE: 000882.062   sp+10 00000000 0001104f 0001106e 61000010
CONSOLE: 
CONSOLE: 000882.062 sp+14 0001104f
CONSOLE: 000882.062 sp+54 00011671
CONSOLE: 000882.062 sp+15c 0001d61b
CONSOLE: 000882.062 sp+194 0002305d
CONSOLE: 000882.063 sp+1bc 00008121
CONSOLE: 000882.063 sp+1dc 000026fd
CONSOLE: 000882.063 sp+1ec 00002041
CONSOLE: 000882.063 sp+238 000029db
CONSOLE: 000882.063 sp+258 000029db
CONSOLE: 000882.063 sp+268 00002223
CONSOLE: 000882.063 sp+270 00003031
dhdsdio_checkdied: msgtrace address : 0x00000000
console address  : 0x0007DEBC
Assrt not built in dongle
Dongle trap type 0xc @ epc 0x1106e, cpsr 0x6000000c, spsr 0x61000010, sp 0x7fd84,lp 0x1104f, rpc 0x1106e Trap offset 0x7fd30, r0 0x2d, r1 0x7dab4, r2 0x1, r3 0x0, r4 0x7ad68, r5 0xed796108, r6 0x4d5fa, r7 0xda
dhdsdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
dhd_start_xmit: xmit rejected pub.up=1 busstate=0 
dhd_start_xmit: Event HANG sent up
CFG80211-ERROR) wl_cfg80211_disconnect : Reason 3
dhd_prot_ioctl : bus is down. we have nothing to do
dhd_check_hang: Event HANG send up due to  re=0 te=0 e=-1 s=0
dhd_check_hang: Event HANG send up due to  re=0 te=0 e=-1 s=0
CFG80211-ERROR) wl_cfg80211_disconnect : error (-1)
dhd_stop: Enter d712f800
dhd_prot_ioctl : bus is down. we have nothing to do
CFGP2P-ERROR) wl_cfgp2p_bss_isup : 'cfg bss -C 0' failed: -1
CFGP2P-ERROR) wl_cfgp2p_bss_isup : NOTE: this ioctl error is normal when the BSS has not been created yet.
dhd_prot_ioctl : bus is down. we have nothing to do
dhd_prot_ioctl : bus is down. we have nothing to do
CFGP2P-ERROR) wl_cfgp2p_set_management_ie : vndr ie set error : -1
dhd_prot_ioctl : bus is down. we have nothing to do
CFG80211-ERROR) wl_dongle_down : WLC_DOWN error (-1)
dhd_stop: Exit
CFG80211-ERROR) wl_cfg80211_hang : In : chip crash eventing
cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
cfg80211:  DFS Master region FCC
cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 1700 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm)
Error getting the SSID
dhd_prot_ioctl : bus is down. we have nothing to do
dhd_arp_get_arp_hostip_table: ioctl WLC_GET_VAR error -1
dhd_prot_ioctl : bus is down. we have nothing to do
dhd_aoe_hostip_clr failed code -1
aoe_update_host_ipv4_table failed
dhd_open: Enter d712f800
dhd_conf_read_nv_by_chip: nv_by_chip_count=3
dhd_conf_read_nv_by_chip: chip=0xa9a6, chiprev=0, name=nvram_ap6212.txt
dhd_conf_read_nv_by_chip: chip=0xa9a6, chiprev=1, name=nvram_ap6212a.txt
dhd_conf_read_nv_by_chip: chip=0x4345, chiprev=6, name=nvram_ap6255.txt
dhd_conf_set_fw_name_by_chip: firmware_path=/lib/firmware/ap6212/fw_bcm43438a1.bin
dhd_conf_set_nv_name_by_chip: nvram_path=/lib/firmware/ap6212/nvram_ap6212a.txt
dhdsdio_download_firmware: set use_rxchain 0
dhdsdio_download_firmware: set txglomsize 40
sdioh_set_mode: set txglom_mode to multi-desc
Final fw_path=/lib/firmware/ap6212/fw_bcm43438a1.bin
Final nv_path=/lib/firmware/ap6212/nvram_ap6212a.txt
Final conf_path=/lib/firmware/ap6212/config.txt
NVRAM version: AP6212_NVRAM_V1.0_20140603
dhdsdio_write_vars: Download, Upload and compare of NVRAM succeeded.
dhd_bus_init: enable 0x06, ready 0x06 (waited 0us)
bcmsdh_oob_intr_register: Enter
bcmsdh_oob_intr_register: irq is already registered
dhd_bus_start Host failed to register for OOB
dhd_open: failed with code -19
dhd_stop: Enter d712f800
dhd_stop: Exit
dhd_open: Exit ret=-1
dhd_open: Enter d712f800
dhd_open: Exit ret=0
dhd_stop: Enter d712f800
dhd_stop: Exit
gmac0: probed
gmac0 gmac0: eth0: eth0: PHY ID 00441400 at 0 IRQ poll (gmac0-0:00)
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
dhd_open: Enter d712f800
dhd_open: Exit ret=0
wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

The [banana-pi.org wiki](http://wiki.banana-pi.org/Banana_Pi_BPI-M2_ZERO) says that AP6212 is used for wifi, but lshw lists the driver as "wl"

```
$ lshw -C network
*-network:0
     description: Wireless interface
     physical id: 3
     logical name: wlan0
     serial: 8c:f7:10:1e:ff:e0
     capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl driverversion=0 ip=192.168.86.81 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

and I can't load the wl driver

```
$ modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/3.4.113-BPI-M2Z-Kernel
```

Is wlan0 using the wrong driver?

Comment: `wl` seems to be used as a prefix. Try `modprobe` on some of `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name 'wl*'`

Comment: `wl12xx_spi.ko, wl12xx_sdio.ko, wl12xx.ko, wl1251_sdio.ko, wl1251_spi.ko, wl1251.ko, wl1273-core.ko`